# Display box after actionButton is pressed in a shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have the shiny app below and I would like the `box` to be displayed only when the `actionButton` is pressed. Otherwise it is confusing for the user as he sees an empty box without the plot.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

shinyApp(
  ui = tags$body(class="skin-blue sidebar-mini control-sidebar-open",dashboardPage(
    options = list(sidebarExpandOnHover = TRUE),
    header = dashboardHeader(title = "Investment Advisor Monitoring - Insider Trading",titleWidth = 450),
    
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(minified = F, collapsed = F,
                               actionButton("go", "Go"),
                               numericInput("n", "n", 50)
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      box(
        title = "StockPrice Reaction Around The Event Date", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
        collapsible = TRUE,
      plotOutput("plot"))
      
    ),
    title = "DashboardPage"
  )),
  server = function(input, output) { 
    
    randomVals <- eventReactive(input$go, {
      runif(input$n)
    })
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      hist(randomVals())
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `shinyjs::hidden()` & `shinyjs::show()` together with `observeEvent()`.

Your example now becomes:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- tags$body(
  class="skin-blue sidebar-mini control-sidebar-open", 
  
  dashboardPage(
    options = list(sidebarExpandOnHover = TRUE), 
    
    # ----header----
    header = dashboardHeader(
      title = "Investment Advisor Monitoring - Insider Trading",
      titleWidth = 450
    ), 
    
    # ----sidebar----
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      minified = FALSE, 
      collapsed = FALSE,
      actionButton("go", "Go"),
      numericInput("n", "n", 50)
    ), 
    
    # ----body----
    body = dashboardBody(
      useShinyjs(), # MUST include this line
      
      # ----hiddenbox----
      shinyjs::hidden(
        div(
          id = "hiddenbox", 
          
          box(
            title = "StockPrice Reaction Around The Event Date", 
            status = "primary", 
            solidHeader = TRUE,
            collapsible = TRUE,
            plotOutput("plot")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  randomVals <- eventReactive(input$go, {
    runif(input$n)
  })
  
  # ----show hiddenbox----
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    shinyjs::show(id = "hiddenbox")
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(randomVals())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thanks a lot it works